# Converting string dates to numeric dates

Tags: r

I want to convert this kind of dates :`Apr 09, 2019` to this kind of dates: `Apr 09, 2019-04-09`

I wrote

`as.Date(Data$date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
format(as.Date(Data$date, format = "%B %d, %Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")`

That code worked, however when I `View(Data)` I see that it had not converted.

Why? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the column is not updated.  We need to assign (`<-`) the results back to the original column or a new column

```
Data$date <- format(as.Date(Data$date, format = "%B %d, %Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
```